# Error in `dplyr::left_join()`: !`...` must be empty

Tags: dplyr

I'm trying to join two datasets using the
`funciton dplyr::left_join()`

```
DataSet12 <- dplyr::left_join(Dataset1, Dataset2[,6:8], by = "IDxax", all = T)
```

However, it returs an error

```
Error in `dplyr::left_join()`:
! `...` must be empty.
x Problematic argument:
 all = T

Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error ocurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlib_error_dots_nonempty>
Error in `dplyr::left_join()`:
! `...` must be empty.
x Problematic argument:
 all = T
```

Any help with this would be very much appracited

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

`all=T` is not a argument of `dplyr::left_join()`

So you would need to run

```
DataSet12 <- dplyr::left_join(Dataset1, Dataset2[,6:8], by = "IDxax")
```

`all=L` is a parameter of the `merge()` function, where `L` is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: Thank you very much stefan_aus_hanover, this works now

Comment: @Virgilio don't forget to upvote and accept your most useful answers on StackOverflow